# gdb commands on bin file does not work for my binary file

Tags: gdb, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to use gdb to revese engineer a `.bin` file. I've tried following a bunch of guides, but every single thing I do seems to fail.

First I just open the file with gdb:

```
$ gdb impossible_password.bin 
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04) 9.2
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from impossible_password.bin...
(No debugging symbols found in impossible_password.bin)
```

I try to disassemble main:

```
(gdb) disassemble main
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
```

Ok, strange, this worked in the video I saw about it. What am I doing wrong here?

Also, I saw another video, where a guy started the file, and could set breakpoints, using location id's from ghidra. I Also wanted to try this:

```
$ gdb impossible_password.bin 
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04) 9.2
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from impossible_password.bin...
(No debugging symbols found in impossible_password.bin)
(gdb) start
Function "main" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Temporary breakpoint 1 (-qualified main) pending.
Starting program: /home/ask/Notes/ethHack/wetransfer-85179d/Export/impossible_password.bin 
* b *00400961
[b]
[Inferior 1 (process 29475) exited with code 01]
(gdb)
```

Where setting the breakpoint just fails. And I can see absolutely no values inside the file.

What am I doing so absolutely wrong? I really just wanna get started and look at some values inside this file
EDIT:

Here is the info about the file in question:

```
$ file impossible_password.bin
impossible_password.bin: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=ba116ba1912a8c3779ddeb579404e2fdf34b1568, stripped
```

Comment: What output do you get if you type `file impossible_password.bin` in your shell?

Comment: added an edit :)

Comment: This may help! https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/1935

Answer (score 0):

Your `.bin` file is *fully* stripped. This means there are no symbols in it, and every command which requires symbols (such as `break main` and `start`) will fail.

You can only set breakpoints on addresses.

Assuming `0x0400961` is indeed address of `main`, this should work:

```
(gdb) break *0x0400961
(gdb) run
```